# Sending arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, tcp

I have client-server application and i need to send ArrayList from server to client but i have **Error in client** after client launching:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servertest.Computer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at clienttest.Clienttest.main(Clienttest.java:25)
```

In what problem?

**Server code:**

```
package servertest;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Servertest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serve = new ServerSocket(3128, 0,
                InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    Socket skt = serve.accept();  
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
 ArrayList<Computer> Arsend = new ArrayList<Computer>();
   Computer comp1 = new Computer();
    comp1.setProcessor("1.5 GHZ");
                comp1.setRam("512 MB");
                comp1.setHddSize("100 GB");

    Computer comp2 = new Computer();
    comp2.setProcessor("2.5 GHZ");
                comp2.setRam("512 MB");
                comp2.setHddSize("50 GB");

                Arsend.add(comp1);
                Arsend.add(comp2);
  out.writeObject(Arsend);
}}


package servertest;
import java.io.Serializable;
 public class Computer implements Serializable{
 private String Processor;
private String Ram;
private String HddSize;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String getProcessor() {
    return Processor;
}
public void setProcessor(String Processor) {
    this.Processor = Processor;
}
public String getRam() {
    return Ram;
}
public void setRam(String Ram) {
    this.Ram = Ram;
}
public String getHddSize() {
    return HddSize;
}
public void setHddSize(String HddSize) {
    this.HddSize = HddSize;
}}
```

**Client Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
 Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3128);
 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
 ArrayList<Object> receivedList = (ArrayList<Object>)in.readObject();
```

He can't find class when i launch client, problem in last client line, may be i should change something there..., or may be problem in class "Computer"??

Comment: are you using `maven` ?? @bffn

Comment: Try to mention `import servertest.Computer` in `Servertest ` and then again launch client.

Comment: no, i just use NetBeans @VikrantKashyap

Comment: It didn't help:( @AshishPatil

Answer (score -1):

Suggest only if you use `maven` build in `Eclipse`.

I had the same problem. All what I did was,

i). just delete your `.project` and `.classpath` from your project Folder.

ii)  Generated Eclipse artifacts using this command .

`mvn clean eclipse:eclipse`

iii). Refresh the project and rebuild your project. It Should work fine.

Comment: The Eclipse m2e plugin is a much better way to use Maven projects in Eclipse IDE. `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is almost deprecated. What's recommended is to either use the `Import Maven project` Eclipse wizard, or to find `Configure > Configure as Maven project...` context-menu on a project that contains a pom.xml.